# Rreading a multi string argument using Apache commons

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

`o.getValue()` return the value for the option.

But for a multi arg input, say `-h this is a heading`, the function returns only the first string '*this*'; how do I fetch the full param: `this is a heading`.

Comment: Can you please provide more information. For example what Apache Commons library are you talking about? It sounds like Commons CLI.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely to be an issue with how your shell parses the command line.  All shells I know of break up words into separate arguments and you need to use quotes to get around this e.g. `-h "this is a heading"`  All shells work this way and I don't believe you can get around this in Java.